# Elegant way of handling non-existent PHP pages in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

What is the best way of handling non-existent PHP pages in Nginx? I have the following location block...

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'd like to be able to display a 404 error if a PHP page doesn't exist, I'm guessing I need to get the `try_files` (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) directive involved by handling all errors with the `error_page` directive (declared elsewhere), but am unsure of the best way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use error_page(you can change page_not_found.html to php script):

```
error_page 404 /page_not_found.html;
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

try file need to redirect to a different server, if page not found.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, is there something I'm missing in the 'fastcgi_params' include perhaps?

Comment: Try add fastcgi_intercept_errors on

Comment: Uh. Try files does not need to redirect to a different server...